# FPGA blocking assignments in always block not working properly

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, verilog, xilinx, spartan

In the following setup I have created a custom clock through switch on Spartan 3E FPGA to toggle the LED states one by one. I have connected 8 registers with 8 LEDs. By triggering the clock through switch, values of registers are toggled at the positive edge of clock. In each clock one register's value is toggled which is selected by the index variable.

**Verilog Code**

```
module IOCom(
    input wire dataInShiftCLK, dataOutShiftCLK,
    output wire dataOutEnb, 
    output wire [7:0] LED
);

reg [7:0] temp;
integer index; 
reg dataOutEnbReg, dataInShiftCLKReg;

initial begin
    temp <= 8'b00000000;
end

// blocking assignments used
always @ (posedge dataInShiftCLK) begin
    temp[index] = ~temp[index];
    index = index + 1;
    if(index == 8) begin
        dataOutEnbReg = 1;
        index = 0;
    end
end

assign dataOutEnb = dataOutEnbReg;

assign LED[0] = temp[0];
assign LED[1] = temp[1];
assign LED[2] = temp[2];
assign LED[3] = temp[3];
assign LED[4] = temp[4];
assign LED[5] = temp[5];
assign LED[6] = temp[6];
assign LED[7] = temp[7];

endmodule
```

**UCF Code**

```
# ==================
#     SPARTAN 3E
#   xc3s500e-4fg320
# ==================

NET "dataInShiftCLK" LOC = L13 | IOSTANDARD = "LVTTL"; 
NET "dataInShiftCLK" CLOCK_DEDICATED_ROUTE = FALSE;
NET "dataOutEnb" LOC = D7 | IOSTANDARD = "LVCMOS33"; 

NET LED<0> LOC=F12 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33; 
NET LED<1> LOC=E12 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33; 
NET LED<2> LOC=E11 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33; 
NET LED<3> LOC=F11 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33; 
NET LED<4> LOC=C11 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33; 
NET LED<5> LOC=D11 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33; 
NET LED<6> LOC=E9 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33; 
NET LED<7> LOC=F9 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33;
```

**I am facing the following issues**

1. I have used posedge but at negedge the toggling also happen sometime.
2. The LEDs are very unstable and very few times toggling one by one. Some times all toggle at once and some times 3-4 LEDs toggle at once. I tried to fix the issue by using blocking assignment in always block but still not fixed.

Please suggest some solution to fix the issue. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is you switch debounced?

Comment: BTW , "Initial" is not synthesizable. It's a simulation only construct. Thus your TEMP register is not properly reset on FPGA power on. Not the root cause of your issue but something to consider.
I agree that the issue it probable related to the (lack of? ) debouncing of the switch

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will debounce the switch and test again.